# clojure defn pattern matching

Tags: clojure

I am really new to clojure, and I want to simulate `+` from clojure, I wrote something like this:

```
(defn sum
  ([] 0)
  ([x & xs] (+ x (sum xs))))
(sum 1 2 3 4) ; ERROR
```

which is not right, as in Haskell, I can write

```
sum' :: [Int] -> Int
sum' [] = 0
sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' xs
```

What is the problem with the clojure code ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct would be as follows:

```
(defn sum
    ([] 0)
    ([x & xs] (+ x (apply sum xs))))
```

You were calling the function with one argument, a list, thus hitting the second case over and over until recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot!